# Some texts in my PPTs are unable to change its font

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if I'm not doing it right. But when I tried to select a font for my PPT presentation, some words doesn't change at all, no matter what font a chose[![enter image description here]
It happened more than once. For some reasons, my normal typing process would result in a few text blocks that resist any change to the font?[image] Notice I have selected arial body font for 指示，but it doesn‘t change at all!

Comment: Start the Character Map app, choose Arial as the font and verify that the version of Arial installed on your computer actually has the characters you've typed. If not, PowerPoint is likely choosing a different font so that it can supply the needed character.

Comment: I thought that as well.But it doesn’t likely. the characters can’t be changed no matter what don’t I chose

Comment: If that's the case, setting the font to Arial would probably not change the "substitute" font that's being used. If you have Arial Unicode or can install it, it should have a much wider selection of Chinese characters. That might help.

Comment: That is what I originally thought as well. But that can't be the case. From the picture you can see that 指示 is in Arial font before the same character in Songti font. So it is unlikely the strange behavior is because of a lack of characters.

Comment: Can you post a copy of this slide somewhere so anyone who's interested can have a look? That might help.